# Unable to update the GridView in .Net (Date fields are not updating)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datepicker

Below is the code for GridView and query for Update and Insert....But when i update the grid then all values update in the database except DATE(all three fields). after updating  Date fields value is NULL in database... I am using datepicker for calendar.

```
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" ForeColor="#333333" width="1000px"
                GridLines="None"  OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" 
                AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                BorderStyle="Outset" CellSpacing="1" Font-Names="Cambria" 
                Font-Size="Small" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="True" 
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
               >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="case_number" HeaderText="Case Number" 
                        SortExpression="case_number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="case_name" HeaderText="Case Name" 
                        SortExpression="case_name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Case_Type_Text" HeaderText="Case Type" 
                        SortExpression="Case_Type_Text" />

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Status" SortExpression="Case_Status_Text">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Case_Status_Text" DataValueField="Case_Status_Text" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Case_Status_Text") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Case_Status_Text") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:BoundField DataField="assigned_date" HeaderText="Assigned Date" 
                        SortExpression="assigned_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="assigned_to" HeaderText="Assigned To" 
                        SortExpression="assigned_to" />


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Withdrawn" SortExpression="date_withdrawn">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker5" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("date_withdrawn", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Delivered" SortExpression="date_delivered">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker7" runat="server" 
                                />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("date_delivered", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QC By" SortExpression="qc_by">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="User_Name" DataValueField="User_Name" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("qc_by") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_by") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QC Date" SortExpression="qc_date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker6" runat="server" 
                                />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Additional Notes">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("additional_notes") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("additional_notes") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" 
                        CausesValidation="False" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>


            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:con %>" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:con.ProviderName %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [View_Intakesheet]" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [View_Intakesheet] ([case_number], [case_name], [assigned_date], [assigned_to], [date_withdrawn], [date_delivered], [qc_by], [qc_date], [additional_notes], [Case_Status_Text], [Case_Type_Text]) VALUES (@case_number, @case_name, @assigned_date, @assigned_to, @date_withdrawn, @date_delivered, @qc_by, @qc_date, @additional_notes, @Case_Status_Text, @Case_Type_Text)" 
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE intakesheet SET case_number = @case_number, case_name=@case_name, Case_Type=@case_type, Case_Status = @case_status, assigned_date = @assigned_date, assigned_to = @assigned_to, date_withdrawn= @date_withdrawn, date_delivered= @date_delivered, qc_by = @qc_by,  qc_date=@qc_date, additional_notes = @additional_notes WHERE (case_number = @case_number)">
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_number" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_name" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="assigned_date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="assigned_to" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="date_withdrawn" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="date_delivered" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="qc_by" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="qc_date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="additional_notes" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Case_Status_Text" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Case_Type_Text" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_number" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_name" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_type" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="case_status" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="assigned_date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="assigned_to" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="date_withdrawn" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="date_delivered" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="qc_by" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="qc_date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="additional_notes" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
```